# how to block a meta refresh tag?

Tags: html, meta

I was editing a website via its CRM. I put in a

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=https://www.website.com"> in the home body to check if it works.
```

Now I am unable to get rid of this tag. Whenever I try logging in as admin - it keep redirecting me. Any way to stop this? I am stuck. I do not have root access to the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Firefox. 
Type in address bar: `about:config`
search for accessibility.blockautorefresh
Toggle all 3 to true.

Visit your website:

[image]